# Uncaught TypeError: is not a function in Chrome

Tags: javascript

So I'm writing a userscript for a website and I'm encountering this error `Uncaught TypeError:  is not a function` It doesn't occur in Firefox, but does in Chrome. I've spent the last hour debugging with no success.

I've provided the relevant snippets below to reproduce the error in chrome. The script is supposed to find the button containing the text 'Download' and return the href.

```js
function getSubmissionSource(){
  var controlBar = document.getElementsByClassName("button submission rounded");
  for (var button of controlBar) { //errors here
    var link = button.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (link !== undefined && link.textContent == "Download") {
      return link.href;
    }
  }
}
console.log(getSubmissionSource());
```

```html
<div id="test"">
  <span class="button submission rounded">
    <a href="/view/18251152/" class="prev dotted">Older</a>
  </span>
  <span class="button submission rounded">
    <a href="">-Remove from Favorites</a>
  </span>
  <span class="button submission rounded">
    <a href="">Download</a>
  </span>
  <span class="button submission rounded">
    <a href="">Note user</a></span>
  <span class="button submission rounded">
    <a href="/view/18385008/">Newer</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `for (var button` to `for (btn`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `for` loop to iterate through `nodelist`

```js
function getSubmissionSource(){
  var controlBar = document.getElementsByClassName("button submission rounded");
  for (var i=0,iLen=controlBar.length;i<iLen; i++) { //errors here
    var link = controlBar[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (link !== undefined && link.textContent == "Download") {
      return link.href;
    }
  }
}
console.log(getSubmissionSource());
```

```html
<div id="test"">
  <span class="button submission rounded">
    <a href="/view/18251152/" class="prev dotted">Older</a>
  </span>
  <span class="button submission rounded">
    <a href="">-Remove from Favorites</a>
  </span>
  <span class="button submission rounded">
    <a href="">Download</a>
  </span>
  <span class="button submission rounded">
    <a href="">Note user</a></span>
  <span class="button submission rounded">
    <a href="/view/18385008/">Newer</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `of` operator in JavaScript you need to change

```
for (var button of controlBar) {
```

to

```
for (var button in controlBar) {
```

Comment: Although fairly new https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for... but apparently it's not working in chrome like I thought it did.